# Unable to do an executable which works error from polyfit

Tags: python, numpy, cx-freeze

I'm trying to do an executable from python script. For this I use Cx_Freeze. My code is very simple. It appears that there is an error which come from when the computer is interpreting the polyfit line.  This is the first time that I tried to do an executable and i'm not able to see what I should do to resolve my problem. Could you please tell me ?

```
from numpy import polyfit
from time import sleep
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if(len(sys.argv)==1):
        print("There is no argument. Please insert arguments")
        sleep(10)
        sys.exit(0)
    x = list(map(int, sys.argv[1:int((len(sys.argv)-1)/2+1)]))
    y = list(map(int, sys.argv[int((len(sys.argv)-1)/2+1):])) 
    print("Computing : [X datas : " + str(x) + "; Y datas : " + str(y) +"]")
    try: 
        param = polyfit(x, y, 2) ##1 is the degree number 
    except TypeError:
        print("ERROR : X and Y are expected to have same length")
        sleep(10)
        sys.exit(0)
    print("Equation : " + "{0:.6}".format(param[0]) + "x² + " + "{0:.6}".format(param[1]) + "x + " + "{0:.6}".format(param[2]))
```

My Setup py file :

```
import os
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')
additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
additional_files = [(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tcl86t.dll'),
                     os.path.join('lib', 'tcl86t.dll')),
                    (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs', 'tk86t.dll'),
                     os.path.join('lib', 'tk86t.dll'))
                    ]

setup(
      name = "XXX_Polyfit_Computing",
      version = "0.1",
      description = "Compute coefficients of a 2nd order equations",
      options = {'build_exe': {'includes': additional_mods, 
                               'include_files' : additional_files}},
      executables = [Executable("polyfit.py")]
)
```

Here is the error when I passed the correct number of arguments : 
[image]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please post the error message as text, not as an image, see [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/8516269)

Comment: The example you posted works without issue for me after freezng with cx_Freeze 5.1.1. It seems that the issue happens when numpy issues the `RankWarning: Polyfit may be poorly conditioned`. Maybe the problem is caused by the special character in `x²` in your code. Try to replace it by `x^2` or to add the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the beginning of your main script.

Comment: The problem come from my computer indeed. I tried it on an other computer and it works. :D Thank a lot ! (It doesn't come from x²)

Comment: Sounds great. Please add an answer explaining how to solve the issue in a way potentially useful for anyone facing a similar issue, or, if you can't, delete the question.